# Remove from a std::set<shared_ptr<T>> by shared_ptr<const T>

Tags: c++, set, constants, shared-ptr

I have a a function, that essentially boils down to this (the part that I'm struggling with, ignoring the stuff that is actually happening)

```
class CellSorter
{
public:
    bool operator()( std::shared_ptr<const Cell> a,
                     std::shared_ptr<const Cell> b ) const
    {
        return ( ( a->GetY() < b->GetY() ) ||
                 ( a->GetY() == b->GetY() &&
                   a->GetX() < b->GetX() ) );
    }
};
typedef std::set<std::shared_ptr<Cell>, CellSorter> Container;
MyClass::Container MyClass::DoSomething( std::shared_ptr<const Cell> c )
{
    MyClass::Container N;
    // assume that this code works to copy some stuff to N, blah blah blah
    std::remove_copy_if( _grid.begin(), _grid.end(),
                         std::inserter( N, N.begin() ),
                         std::not1( CellIsNeighbor( c->GetX(), c->GetY() ) ) );
    N.erase( c ); // ERROR
    return N;
};
```

The problem is, gcc gives me an error:

> /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/shared_ptr.h:651:
>   error: invalid conversion from ‘const
>   Cell*’ to ‘Cell*’

I thought that this should not be casting the object "c" from `shared_ptr<const Cell>` to `shared_ptr<Cell>`, but somehow it is.  I want c to point to a const Cell because there is no need to modify it.  And the CellSorter shouldn't have a problem with const.

Any ideas as to why I can't do this or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the shared_ptr in Container has type `std::shared_ptr<Cell>`.  You are passing a `std::shared_ptr<const Cell>` to the erase() method.  Different types.  You can fix it by removing the const qualifier.

Apparently you can also use `std::const_pointer_cast` in this situation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982336.aspx

Comment: Okay, so the answer is, I can't do that.  Quick question, does this apply to regular pointers as well?  So if my code had a `std::set<Cell*> container` and I had a variable that was `const Cell * c`, then I still can't do `container.erase(c)`?  It just seems odd to me as I want to keep the const-correctness of `c`, and what I'm doing shouldn't modify it.

Comment: With regular pointers you could use const_cast to remove the const-ness of c.  But I'm not sure that's a tradeoff worth making.  I'd rather use shared_ptr to manage the memory than worry about preserving const in a situation where it may not be justified.

Comment: Okay, yeah I'm sticking with the shared_ptr, it was more of a curiosity.  It just seems like I should be able to pass a const pointer (or smart pointer) to set::erase even if the set holds non-const pointers (or smart pointers).  But hey, I can live with dropping the const in this case.